# how to make inner join in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in trouble when making this inner join query

Original:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY idmicro ORDER BY IdHistMov desc) AS rownum
    FROM dbo.T_HistMovEquip
    ) AS initialResultSet
WHERE initialResultSet.rownum<=2
```

Trying to inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.idmicro ORDER BY c.IdHistMov desc) AS rownum
    FROM dbo.T_HistMovEquip c
    INNER JOIN T_Micro m ON c.Idmicro=m.Idmicro
    ) AS initialResultSet
WHERE initialResultSet.rownum<=2
```

**this error appears:** The column 'IDMicro' was specified multiple times for 'initialResultSet'.

Thank You!

Comment: Don't use `*` in general but list all columns, use aliases if a column appears multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not just specify the columns you want. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.idmicro, 
        c.IdHistMov,
        /*And so on*/
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.idmicro ORDER BY c.IdHistMov desc) AS rownum
    FROM 
        dbo.T_HistMovEquip c
        INNER JOIN T_Micro m 
            ON c.Idmicro=m.Idmicro
    ) AS initialResultSet
WHERE initialResultSet.rownum<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your using `Select *` when clearly you have the same column name ( IDMicro ) in both tables. Try to "filter" the output selection to only the columns you are interested in OR use column aliases if you need the same column names from both tables.